# MP4 html5 video not working on IE10

Tags: html, apache, video

I have a video and I want to display it on a webpage. I have saved it in several formats, an for IE i am using an MP4 file encoded with H.264.

I have tried both the video and the HTML code on my PC, and it works, but what I upload it to the server it doesnt (it says the media type is not compatible). I have tried accessing the video from the HTML page on my PC, and it gives the same error, so I think the error may be on the server sending an incorrect MIME TYPE (I have already specified "video/mp4" on the video tag).

Do you guys know how can I fix it?

```
<video controls autoplay  poster="images/logobig.png" style="width:610px;">
<source src="videos/1.mp4"  type="video/mp4" />
<source src="videos/1.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
<source src="videos/1.webm" type="video/webm"  />
Your browser does not support HTML5
 </video>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I solved it, adding

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
```

to .htaccess

Comment: Didn't work for me. Did you do anything else too @Arcadio Garcia?

Comment: @eFriend Nope, just that, sorry.