# Stuck in "error unsupported video type or invalid file path" using HTML5 in IE10

Tags: html, jsp

Following is my code for video using HTML5;

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">     
<html> 
   <head> 
   </head> 
   <body> 
     <video id="video" controls src="${maps.url }" height="598" width="782"> 
        Your user agent     does not support the HTML5 Video element. 
     </video> 
   </body> 
</html>
```

It works fine in Chrome with correct URL. In IE10, however, it gets correct URL but it displays an error message;

```
error unsupported video type or invalid file path
```

Can anyone help me what to add in the code to enable it in IE10 as well?

Comment: Related (possibly duplicate) questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15639444/1883647), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18500282/1883647), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275225/mp4-html5-video-not-working-on-ie10). MSDN has a [guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh924821%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for doing this if you haven't seen it yet. What does `${maps.url }` render into? Do you have a `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of your page? Also, your `X-UA-Compatible` meta tag should be inside of `<head>` (you also need `<title>` in `<head>` to have a valid HTML page).

Comment: ${maps.url } brings the URL from the DB.
<!DOCTYPE html> does not need close tag, correct?

Comment: The actual URL may be helpful to us, particularly with the file type. `DOCTYPE` does not need a closing tag.