# How to embed a video in HTML that works in IE

Tags: html, video

I'm trying to embed some videos in my HTML. However, the video doesn't work in IE 10 and says invalid source. Here's what I have:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="banana.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="banana.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support this video!
</video>
```

I'm not even getting the message saying that the video isn't supported. Could this be a problem with my video?

Comment: You've confirmed the video works in another browser such as Chrome?

Comment: yep, it works fine in chrome and firefox

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fix that appears to be working for people. Simply install  **Windows Media Player** if you don't have it. Also your video file must be in the same folder as your HTML page on the server

Comment: yes, it seems I'm not able to play my video in Windows Media Player but I can in every other player. Do you guys know if I can "fix" a video to work in WMP?

Comment: are there any other file formats that I could convert my video to that would work?

Answer (score 0):

try adding:

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
```

to .htaccess hope it could help :)

or you can view this link :
[MP4 html5 video not working on IE10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275225/mp4-html5-video-not-working-on-ie10)

Answer (score 0):

I used this in one of my project

```
<video width="640" height="360" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
     <source src="videopath" type="video/mp4">
     <object  data="" width="640" height="360">
     <embed width="640" height="360" src="videopath"> 
</object>
 </video>
```