# Fetching the link to a video from an RSS feed item

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, rss, html5-video

I am new to web development and this is my first Chrome extension. Here is my script to fetch and parse RSS feeds :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // FETCH THE RSS FEEDS AND PARSE THEM
    $.get(rssurl, function(data) {
      var $xml = $(data);
      $xml.find("item").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            item = {
                     title: $this.find("title").text(),
                     link: $this.find("link").text(),
                     description: $this.find("description").text(),
                     pubDate: $this.find("pubDate").text(),
                     url : $this.find("enclosure").attr("url"),
                     author: $this.find("author").text()
                   };

        // ADD IT TO THE ARRAY
        items.push(item);
        if(items.length == 1){
          $(".title").html(item.title);
          $(".description").html(item.url);
          $(".author").html(item.author);

          $(video).attr({"src" : item.url});
        }
      });// end of each()
    });// end of $.get()
});
```

The problem, however is this:

```
url : $this.find("enclosure").attr("url"),
```

The idea is to get the video to play which does not despite it being in `.mp4`.
Here are the feeds that I am parsing: http://feeds.podtrac.com/tTKj5t05olM$

*N.B. I have allowed all URLs in my chrome manifest*

Comment: So... you only want to fetch items which are in mp4 format?

Comment: Yes and display its video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here :

```
$(video).attr({"src" : item.url});
```

It needs to be :

```
$("video").attr("src",item.url);
```

Comment: Invalid selector is the major cause of video display issue. Both attr(string,value) and attr({string:value}) can set the value of attribute of element. Attr({string:value}) can set several attributes at once.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add below condition before you add item to array:

```
if($("enclosure[url$='.mp4']",this).length>0){}
```

[attribute$="value"] is jQuery attribute end with selector. It will select element that have the specified attribute with a value ending with a given string.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // FETCH THE RSS FEEDS AND PARSE THEM
    $.get(rssurl, function(data) {
      var $xml = $(data);
      $xml.find("item").each(function() {
        //if item's enclosure url attribute is in .mp4 format... then add it to the video array
        if($("enclosure[url$='.mp4']",this).length>0){
          var $this = $(this),
              item = {
                       title: $this.find("title").text(),
                       link: $this.find("link").text(),
                       description: $this.find("description").text(),
                       pubDate: $this.find("pubDate").text(),
                       url : $this.find("enclosure").attr("url"),
                       author: $this.find("author").text()
                     };

          // ADD IT TO THE ARRAY
          items.push(item);

          if(items.length == 1){
            $(".title").html(item.title);
            $(".description").html(item.url);
            $(".author").html(item.author);

            $(video).attr({"src" : item.url});
          }
        }
      });// end of each()
    });// end of $.get()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your mp4 files are not properly formatted to play in an HTML5 video tag.

When I open http://media.tqaweekly.com/video/tqa-se4ep29.mp4 in firefox I get an error stating the video is corrupted. In Chrome I have audio but no video.

I solved this for another stacker [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22926844/html5-video-video-unsupported-invalid-file-type-ie). I think it is something similar.

After that you need to display the video in an HTML5 video tag. But I guess you do not need help for that :)

```
<video width="640" height="360" controls>
  <source src="yoursrc.mp4"  type="video/mp4; codecs=avc1.42E01E,mp4a.40.2">
</video>
```

Comment: I tried [this RSS FEED](http://feeds.twit.tv/aaa_video_hd.xml) but to no avail. :(

Comment: Can you try this one: http://api.ooyala.com/syndication/mp4?id=00d1c219-1b16-4273-a591-3bfb5bf7f2fc

Comment: Files inside do not end in .mp4 but they are valid mp4, example http://ak.c.ooyala.com/NjbGoxMjqMRw66RZJJ993wWRxux7Z4cf/DOcJ-FxaFrRg4gtGUwOmk2OjBrOxit_Y, I know those files are properly formatted.

Comment: See my answer to my own question :)

Comment: Ok glad you could sort it out