# Video not Buffereing

Tags: php, video, flowplayer

I am currently building a website [opensourceeducation.in](http://opensourceeducation.in). It is a video hosting website. I am using [flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org) for playing videos. My problem is when i play the video it takes alot of time to load. On doing inspect element i can see the whole video is loaded into the cache and then played, instead of buffereing the video part by part. I am using godaddy hosting to host my website. Any help welcome. Thank you.
Below given is my player code.

```
<div id="flow" class="flowplayer aside-time play-button center is-splash" data-ratio="0.5625" data-volume="0.5" style="background:black;width: 100%;margin-top:2em;">

<video >
   <source id="palyer" type="video/mp4" src="<?php echo $result->location?>"></source>
    Your Browser Is Not Supported     
</video>
</div>
```

Comment: I think it really depends on your server settings rather than the code you are showing.

Comment: @putvande Thanks for your reply. Can you explain abit? which settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe seems to indicate a problem with the format of your mp4. It needs to be optimized for streaming (aka fast start).

Have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22926844/html5-video-video-unsupported-invalid-file-type-ie). I solved it already for another stacker.

Let us know if it works for you

Comment: Thanks @Florestan06 it was of great help. Now videos are buffering well but I am still having trouble making them play on android devices. Any advices? This website is primarily targeted for portable device users.

Comment: read here: http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html under section "Issues on Android devices"

Comment: I think your initial issue has been solved. If it is the case you can accept the answer. If you still have specific issue on Android please ask a new question with further details. Thanks