# Video stream choppy on first load, IIS 7 and Windows Server 2008

Tags: html, iis, video-streaming, html5-video, umbraco

After few days of debugging various loading issues with one website we've been working on we came to conclusion that there's an issue with streaming video files (mp4, ogv and webm format) under IIS7/IIS7.5 and Windows Server 2008.

We have two versions of website, one is running on PHP (custom made CMS solution) and the other one is running on Umbraco.

When nginx is serving video content, no video chopping is experienced.

Any ideas what could be an issue?
To play the video, we're using HTML5  tag:

```
<video autoplay="autoplay" class="largeVideo" loop="loop" muted>
  <source src="/media/1123/ai-intro-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="/media/1124/ai-intro-video.ogv" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="/media/1126/ai-intro-video.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

I can't provide website URL, but you can check out Umbraco's website - this video is delivered in pretty much the same way (even design-wise it's looking similar).

Mime-types are added correctly, disabling compression didn't change anything.
Video is choppy even if played by directly targeting video URL.

We've tested website on few servers and from different locations, and results are pretty much the same.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to consider:

- I tried Umbraco on my firefox 28 Windows 8.1 and it looked ok. On Chrome 34 I have noticed some stuttering but only some.
- Have you not some specific hooks for your application that may involve IIS but not Nginx?
- If you do not use pure streaming for delivery to HTML5 video (like DASH or HLS) content is progressively downloaded to the browser cache for playback. So in "theory" playback should not relate to your server being X or Y once file is properly downloaded.
  However if your page uses much CPU for other JS or else tasks you may experience stuttering at playback when frames are decoded to be displayed (especially if you target HD content). Is your video choppy when you only have one HTML5 video tag on a blank page - having preload attribute set to auto and autoplay disabled?

I have had a similar issue with one of my [Apache server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22981368/html5-video-video-buffered-length-returns-0-on-ie-10-11) and Internet explorer. I would suggest you tried the following steps:

- wild card CORS (msdn suggested that)
- check your web sever supports ranges request/206 partial content. I have used CURL to check this on my server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We don't have any IIS specific hooks that I'm aware of. Considering that Umbraco website is working fine, I assume it's not umbraco related issue (I fail to see how it could be). Content isn't HD, it's relativly small video file (around 6 mb). This shouldn't be an issue. Same thing is happening with blank page. Server does support 206 and that's header it's sending to browser when it's playing file. I compared headers with Umbraco website and they both seem quite similar.